# Does Appengine flex environment supports Quartz?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, quartz-scheduler, jobs

Afaik, Appengine is not compatible with multithreaded job scheduling like quartz on Standard environment. I just want to know if Appengine Flexi environment have support for it.

Answer (score 1):

The Appengine Flex is an environment with no software usage limitations. It is just a Compute engine VM instance. However, you will not be able to use GAE Datastore (Objectify etc.), which is automatically bound to the GAE Standard environment